# Can you help me with a LINQ query?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I got this MySQL query and I would like to change this to LINQ query.

MySQL:

```
SELECT
    id,
    cas_poziadavky,
    nazov_linky,
    stanica,
    cas_prichodu,
    meno_udrzbara,
    pricina_problemu,
    riesenie_problemu,
    cas_odchodu,
    bol_prestoj,
    poznamka,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cas_poziadavky, cas_odchodu) AS rozdiel',
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cas_poziadavky, cas_prichodu) AS 'reakcia',
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cas_prichodu, cas_odchodu) AS 'vyriesenie'
FROM 
    monitor_linky
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry, we cannot help you with LINQ query, because you provided only SQL query. We don't know what is wrong with your LINQ query. Please add it to question and describe what is wrong

Comment: problem is, I dont know, how to write LINQ , I would like create LINQ query from this SQL query

Comment: No. You would like *us* to create LINQ from this SQL query, because you don't know LINQ

Comment: exactly, can you help me with this?

Comment: Either you learn LINQ or use [LINQPAD](https://www.linqpad.net/) for basic queries to convert to LINQ but i recommend to learn LINQ first as SO is not a tutorial community

Comment: "I dont know, how to write LINQ"... In that case, Google "LINQ tutorial". Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just translate your query like this sample:

```
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =  
from cust in db.Customers  
where cust.City == "London"  
select cust;
```

This link may provide you more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx

Hope this help you :)